# Fan humidity switch doesn't install

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, exhaust-fan

I'm trying to install a humidity sensing switch for a bathroom fan that requires a neutral. There are two switches in the box, one for a light, one for the fan. There are 3 white wires (assuming they are neutrals) in the box twisted together. However, when I hook up the load, line, and pigtail to the neutral bundle, the switch doesn't work. Am I missing something? Every install video I've watched shows connecting it exactly as I have it, but mine won't work. I've tried 2 switches, just in case the switch was bad.

Update: Switch model is Leviton R02-IPHS5-0LW 
[Switch Model http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/400/43/43ea781d-e83f-41d3-98c2-90fec341f3c6_400.jpg](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/400/43/43ea781d-e83f-41d3-98c2-90fec341f3c6_400.jpg)

Photos:
[image: switchbox wires]
[image: switches connected]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box?

Comment: The model of the switch would also be helpful.

Comment: added switch model and photos of wiring to post

Answer (score 1):

This one is simple -- you have the "line" and "load" terminals on the fan controller swapped, assuming the wire that is going to both the fan and the light switches is the line going in.  The red screw (i.e. the screw on the same side as the silver neutral screw) is the load terminal, while there is a brass(?) screw on the opposite side of the device that is the line terminal -- they are also marked RD/WH/BK on the back of the device.  Turn the circuit off at the breaker, and swap the two terminals -- you will need to swap the pigtail from the other switch over to the BK/brass screw on the device as well.